# Is there a practical way to provoke/create AC power line noise?

Tags: noise

We are suspicious of AC power line noise(common mode or differential) aka dirty electricity which sometimes appear and affect some other sensitive equipment. But we are not sure if this random noise is due to conducting high freq. noise through AC power lines.

I tried to turn on and off a vacuum cleaner next to the sensitive setup but it did not provoke anything. Is it futile to try to create such noise for short period of time? Or is there a practical way worth to try?

Comment: Get a long extension cord, loop it around several times, stick a lamp at the end of it, and throw it over the DUT.

Comment: An arc welder will produce ample line noise.

Comment: Use a noisy handheld power tool. Maybe a wet/dry vaccuum or a circular saw. Plug it in to the same outlet as the sensitive equipment. You can also investigate if it is possible to rent test equipment designed to inject noise onto the power lines (this exists, but I don't know the details).

Comment: What you want to do is very similar to "conducted immunity testing." Try googling that. If you wanted to do this in an easy, professional way, and you have a budget, the way to do it is to rent the appropriate gear and research how to use it. Here is one example, just to get you started: NSG 3040. I found this by google search. Not really familiar with this specific item. Another useful search term might be "electrical fast transient" or "EFT." Good luck.

Comment: Kitchen blenders are wonderful, with those sparks in the motor commutator.